# specifying color gradient for aes fill in ggplot/geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm trying to use ggplot to make a bar plot, and am using two different lists of pvalues to gradient-fill (i) the bar plots themselves and (ii) text labels I place on each bar. I've come up and scoured the internet to make this

```
ggplot(plots, aes(x=names, y=values)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=pvalues1)+
  geom_text(aes(x=names y=values, color=pvalues2),fontface="bold", 
                hjust=ifelse(sign(meanScore)>0, 1, 0))
```

The problem here is that it uses the same default blue gradient to fill in both the bars and the labels. Is there any way to specify that one of these use a different gradient? It looks pretty nauseating right now. Thank you!

Comment: You could set the colors used for the gradient using e.g. `scale_colour_gradient` for `color` and/or `scale_fill_gradient` for `fill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using `scale_colour_gradient`!!!